# Collaborative editing and voting application

Tags: webapp-rec, collaboration

Background: I have a university group assignment which, to keep it simple, involves interviewing someone. To work on the questions to ask, I want everyone in the our group to:

- **add** possible ideas
- **edit** other peoples' contributions
- **vote** on existing ones

So what I'm really after is something like a private Stack Exchange with a single Community Wiki question for <10 people.

Already tried Google Wave, Scribblar, Dabbleboard, Slatebox, Waveboard and Shareflow. But none of them (correct me if I'm wrong) have the basic ability to vote!

If what I'm asking is too much, I'd honestly be happy with a private portal that simply allows voting.

Comment: doesn't it make more sense to migrate to softwarerecs than close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [fasterplan](http://www.fasterplan.com). It has a basic poll feature with multiple users for voting on things.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Google Moderator](https://www.google.com/moderator). The only drawback I see is that it's not private. If the quesitons you're voting on are not too confidential and the timeframe is rather short I think it should be hard to find your site. But be aware that, as far as I know, it's still publicly visible. Try if you can see the [test site](https://www.google.com/moderator/#16/e=2aa40) I created.

Comment: nice, never even knew about Moderator. Going to trial it on my own domain!

Comment: Google Moderator has been retired.

Answer (score 0):

How about [trello](http://trello.com) - it has voting, and can be made private. It's simple to use and should do what you need.